# Directory won't be created inside of script

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I'm trying to set up a directory structure inside of a shell script. I dont fully understand how the folder permissions on this work.

If I change the permissions I can create directories inside the folder.

```
sudo chown -R julian data
mkdir $HOME/Documents/neo4j-multi-image/3.5/data/databases
```

But if I try this inside of a shell script it won't work anymore.

sudo run.sh
(inside script code below)

```
chown -R julian data
mkdir $HOME/Documents/neo4j-multi-image/3.5/data/databases
```

using sudo inside of the script does not help either, and I read its not recommended to do that even.

What is going on here?

Kind regards,
Julian

Comment: Mind that a mkdir that does not work will throw an error. If it does not and you did not discard the error it DID execute the mkdir just not where you expected it. Please make sure $HOME has the value you expect it to have by printing it before executing.

Comment: As **Who** (username) are you running the script? Is it the same user you use to run these commands outside of the script? What is the error message you get?

Comment: This is probably what caused it. I did echo $HOME and it told me /root which is not the right directory. Thank you!

Comment: I set HOME="/home/julian" in the beginning in the script to reset the home variable and now it works perfect! Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why do you chown a relative path in a script (`data`)? Why do you use `$HOME` anyways if you assign it an hard-coded value, why not use this value directly? And why do you use `sudo` at all, to me it seems it should not be necessary here?